# WIX installer does not display disk cost in windows 7

Tags: installation, wix, wix3

I am using WIX installer for creating setups.

The disk cost feature works fine on windows server 2003 but it shows 0(zero) KB for the feature. It shows 'compiling cost for the feature'

Can someone please guide me on how to make the disk cost feature work on windows 7, windows server 2008, etc.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there's a solution for this.

This is a known bug in WIX.
Hence closing the question.